# SQL Server metadata: How to get description for columns in views

Tags: sql-server, metadata, database-schema

SQL Server allows storing metadata like description for a table and its columns. The description for the columns can be retrieved from sys.extended_properties. There is also a way to set the description for a view (using the properties window). But there is no way (or at least I am not aware of at this moment) to put the description of a column in a view.

For a particular development, we are keeping the descriptions in the database itself. This allows us to keep it in a single place and do a reporting on it.

We wished to extend the same to include the views as well.

Can somebody help in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine using SSMS 2008. Use the Object Explorer and select properties of the column in the view.

It does not work with SSMS 2005. You will get an exception `Alter failed for Column 'ColumnName'. View columns cannot be modified or created. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)`.

But you can use SSMS 2008 to add the meta data to a SQL Server 2005 database.

Comment: @Kangkan – Using SSMS 2008 it works for both tables and views. With SSMS 2005 it works for tables but not with views.

Comment: Its great to knonw this. However the column MS_Description is to be added. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Another thought, can I pull in the description from the base tables for the views?

Comment: @Kangkan – Yes, you find them in `sys.extended_properties`.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, SQL Server supports *storing* and retrieving metadata values against the [columns of a view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190243.aspx), but I don't think Management Studio supports anything like the properties window for it.

You can maintain the description, etc, by using [sp_addextendedproperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180047.aspx) and its related functions, e.g.:

```
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty 
@name = N'Description', 
@value = 'Postal Code lorem ipsum...',
@level0type = N'Schema', @level0name = 'dbo',
@level1type = N'View',  @level1name = 'MyView',
@level2type = N'Column', @level2name = 'PostCodeColumn';
```

Comment: This way, it will be very hard for updating columns for all the views. What I am looking for is an interactive way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a bypass solution. Create a Table for each view and from there it will be the same thing you were doing. Let's say, you have a view as `VIEW_TEMP`, then write:

```
SELECT * INTO TABLE_FOR_VIEW_TEMP FROM VIEW_TEMP
```

A table will be created and you can work with your documentation.

Comment: Documentation is not the final goal. The goal is to maintain the documentation and the structure side by side. For that matter, the documentation can be kept in a word doc also, but maintaining two disjoint is a pain and you are proposing something similar.